# 12.04 package management corrupted

Tags: 12.04, package-management

I have a 12.04 ubuntu system where I am unable to add any packages.  We think what happened was that a partition became 100% full, and an upgrade got partially completed and now the package management is in a bad state.

Output of uname:

```
$ uname -a
Linux right 3.13.0-93-generic #140~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 19 19:55:11 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

When I add a package I get a dependency error:

```
$ sudo apt-get install netperf
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-headers-generic-lts-trusty : Depends: linux-headers-3.13.0-93-generic but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Installing the dependency fails:

```
$ sudo apt-get  install linux-headers-3.13.0-93-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-headers-3.13.0-93-generic : Depends: linux-headers-3.13.0-93 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Trying to install the linux-headers-3.13.0-93 dependency also fails:

```
$ sudo apt-get install linux-headers-3.13.0-93
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-headers-generic-lts-trusty : Depends: linux-headers-3.13.0-93-generic but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Running "sudo apt-get -f install" hits the same issue:

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-3.13.0-43 linux-tools-3.2.0-102 linux-headers-3.13.0-43-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-generic-lts-trusty
The following packages will be upgraded:
  linux-headers-generic-lts-trusty
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 52 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/2,364 B of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-generic-lts-trusty:
 linux-headers-generic-lts-trusty depends on linux-headers-3.13.0-93-generic; however:
  Package linux-headers-3.13.0-93-generic is not installed.
dpkg: error processing linux-headers-generic-lts-trusty (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic-lts-trusty:
 linux-generic-lts-trusty depends on linux-headers-generic-lts-trusty; however:
  Package linux-headers-generic-lts-trusty is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing linux-generic-lts-trusty (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-headers-generic-lts-trusty
 linux-generic-lts-trusty
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The commands:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

...have no effect on the issue.

Trying "dist-upgrade" also fails:

```
$ sudo apt-get -u dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-headers-generic-lts-trusty : Depends: linux-headers-3.13.0-93-generic but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Anyone have ideas on how to get things working?

Thanks,
Stuart

Comment: Have you edited your sources.list file or added any repos/ppa?

Comment: Based on the timestamp, sources.list has not been touched.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by downloading the packages and then installing using dpkg.

```
sudo apt-get download linux-headers-3.13.0-93-generic  
sudo apt-get download linux-headers-3.13.0-93
```

Then:

```
sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-3.13.0-93_3.13.0-93.140~precise1_all.deb  
sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-3.13.0-93-generic_3.13.0-93.140~precise1_amd64.deb
```

After that, things worked.